# a single bread a day or a single bread per day?

Tags: grammar

> He can survive on a single bread per day.
>
> He can survive on a single bread a day.

Do both mean the same thing or not?

Comment: "A single bread" is not good English because **bread** is a non-count noun. Do you mean a single *slice of* bread, a single *crust of* bread, a single *loaf of* bread, a single *pallet of* bread...?

Comment: In English we never say "two breads" we use **some bread** or **some pieces/slices of bread**. To represent a portion, we can say **a slice**, **a piece**, **a chunk** or  use a weight measurement e.g. **50gr of bread**. .

Comment: @Mari-LouA Never say never.  "Two breads" is fine if we mean two different kinds or varieties of bread (e.g., sourdough and pumpernickel).

Comment: In some languages the same word can be use countably and non-countably (e.g. in  French _du pain_ means 'some bread'  and _un pain_ is a loaf, and _un petit pain_ is a bread roll) and native speakers of those languages may mistakenly think that is the case in English.

Answer (score 1):

If we add a quantity then

> - He can survive on a single slice of bread per day.
> - He can survive on a single slice of bread a day.

have the same meaning. Both are natural. The "per" form is slightly more formal.